# Can I write, $|x^TAy|^{\alpha} \leq \|x\|^{\alpha}\|A\|^{\alpha}\|y\|^{\alpha}$?

Tags: matrices, inequality

I am trying to prove an inequality, and I am stuck in this step. I have a scalar raised to some fractional power i.e., $|x^TAy|^{\alpha}$. Then can I write:
\begin{equation}
|x^TAy|^{\alpha} \leq \|x\|^{\alpha}\|A\|^{\alpha}\|y\|^{\alpha} \leq \|x\|\|A\|\|y\|
\end{equation}
where $0<\alpha\leq 1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$. 
Is the inequality valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $0.5^{0.5} > 0.5$, hence the inequality is not valid.

That is suppose $\|A\|=1, \|y\|=1, \alpha =0.5$ and $\|x\|=0.5$, we have a counterexample.

$$\|x\|^\alpha \|A\|^\alpha \|y\|^\alpha \le \|x\|\|A\|\|y\|$$

is not a valid inequality.

However, we do have

$$|x^TAy|^\alpha \le \|x\|^\alpha \|A\|^\alpha \|y\|^\alpha$$

due to sub-multiplicative and the monotonicity of $f(z)=z^\alpha$.

Comment: Hi @Siong Thye Goh. Thanks for your beautiful answer! I was precisely thinking the same, i.e., a fraction raised to fractional power. But you confirmed my apprehensions. THanks once again!